# Phoenix - where to store globally-accessible functions?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix app, I have a data formatting function that I would like to be accessible to all of my controllers -

```
def prettify({message, values}) do
    Enum.reduce values, message, fn {k, v}, acc ->
        String.replace(acc, "%{#{k}}", to_string(v))
    end
end
```

Where in the file structure of a Phoenix app should globally-accessible functions be included, and how should they be invoked?

Comment: I'd say it's your application structure specific. You can put it into some kind of helper module like `StringsHelper` or something and import it in the `__using__` in your `web.ex` file, as one way to go. Just remember that it's your app and you decide using your best judgement what is put where.

Comment: @JustMichael Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually create a helpers module for the specific area of concert. For example I might have a `web/views/ViewHelpers.ex` or a `web/controllers/ControllerHelpers.ex` file. Then I included them in the respective places in my `web/web.ex` file.

Here is part of my web.ex file for a chat app I'm writing.

```
defmodule UcxChat.Web do
  def service do
    quote do
      import Ecto.Query
      alias UcxChat.{Repo, RoomChannel, UserChannel, Settings}
      alias UcxChat.ServiceHelpers, as: Helpers
      require UcxChat.SharedView
      use UcxChat.Gettext
      import Phoenix.HTML, only: [safe_to_string: 1]
    end
  end

  def controller do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Controller
      use UcxChat.Utils

      alias UcxChat.Repo
      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Query

      import UcxChat.Router.Helpers
      use UcxChat.Gettext
      alias UcxChat.Settings
    end
  end

  def view do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.View, root: "web/templates"

      # Import convenience functions from controllers
      import Phoenix.Controller, only: [get_csrf_token: 0, get_flash: 2, view_module: 1]

      # Use all HTML functionality (forms, tags, etc)
      use Phoenix.HTML
      use UcxChat.Utils

      alias UcxChat.Settings
      import Phoenix.HTML.Tag
      import UcxChat.Router.Helpers
      import UcxChat.ErrorHelpers
      use UcxChat.Gettext
      import UcxChat.SharedView
      require UcxChat.SharedView
      alias UcxChat.Permission
    end
  end

  @doc """
  When used, dispatch to the appropriate controller/view/etc.
  """
  defmacro __using__(which) when is_atom(which) do
    apply(__MODULE__, which, [])
  end
end
```

I have a few helper modules that have macros so you will see a few `use ...` examples in there.

Comment: That's great, just what I was looking for.  Thanks!